# Laravel bearer token authentication

Tags: laravel

I want to make authentication for API requests coming from mobile users.

I followed [this](https://laravel.com/docs/api-authentication)
and made `api_key` column inside `users` table.

I also created middleware:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  $token = $request->bearerToken();
  return $next($token);
}
```

What I want is to get `bearer` token from `header` and check it against user table.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

Append the `auth:api` middleware to any route or group of routes and the Bearer token will be checked automatically for you without a custom middleware

```php
Route::get('url', 'controller@method')->middleware('auth:api');
```

But to answer the question, here's what you can do (still not recommended but works)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ApiAuthentication
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $token = $request->bearerToken();
        $user = \App\User::where('api_token', $token)->first();
        if ($user) {
            auth()->login($user);
            return $next($request);
        }
        return response([
            'message' => 'Unauthenticated'
        ], 403);
    }
}
```

Register the middleware in `App\Http\Kernel`

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    // Here for example
    'custom_auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\ApiAuthentication::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

And protect a route with that middleware name

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    // Return authenticated user model object serialized to json
    return auth()->user();
})->middleware('custom_auth');
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: this worked, can you explain why it's not recommended?

Comment: Because your mobile users aren't supposed to send a weird looking api token, they expect a username and password

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `laravel/passport` as it is much secure and easier.
[Click Here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport)